# Graduate level texts/notes that cover the Short Run and Long Run Costs of firms' production

Tags: microeconomics, reference-request, production-function, firm

In undergrad econ we learned that it would cost a firm more money to increase its production in short term than in long term.

MWG does not seem to cover this topic. I need a Graduate level texts/notes/papers that cover the Short Run and Long Run Costs of firms' production (or supply curve).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Textbooks:

- Mas-Colell, Whinston, and Green (1995). Microeconomic Theory. **Chapter 5**
- Geoffrey Reny. Advanced Microeconomic Theory, 3rd edition. **Chapter 3**
- Kreps (1990). A Course in Microeconomic Theory. **Chapter 7**
- Varian (1992). Microeconomic Analysis, 3rd edition. **Chapter 5**

Lecture notes: I think undergraduate notes are more useful on this respect. For instance:

- Chapter 6 to Chapter 8 [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/economics/14-01-principles-of-microeconomics-fall-2007/lecture-notes/).
- Set 6 and 7 [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/economics/14-04-intermediate-microeconomic-theory-fall-2006/syllabus/) (go to downloads to get slides).

In my experience, graduate notes deal with deeper issues. For instance [this](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/economics/14-121-microeconomic-theory-i-fall-2015/lecture-slides/), [this](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/economics/14-03-microeconomic-theory-and-public-policy-fall-2016/lecture-notes/), or [this](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/economics/14-121-microeconomic-theory-i-fall-2005/syllabus/) one dig much deeper, skipping SR/LR cost functions altogether.

In any case, here Google is your friend. The trick (imo) is to add "pdf" to the search, to get lecture slides. For example:

http://google.com/#q=microeconomics+cost+function+short+run+long+run+pdf